# Best practice for Laravel 4 + Zurb Foundation 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, zurb-foundation

**TL;DR:** what is the best way to arrange files, package managers and build tools for Laravel 4 + Zurb Foundation 5 combo (with Compass) as one consistent repository with clean public (static) section?

---

I wanted to start a fresh project, based on latest Laravel on the backend side and using Foundation for the frontend. I am new to both of these and apparently I missed some of the tooling that was developed meanwhile when I wasn't doing PHP for some time.

My confusion:

- Laravel uses Composer for installation and dependency/module management. (Ok, I'm new to Composer)
- Foundation is available as a Composer module (but then what?), but generally also as a CLI tool that creates a new project and uses bower for module/dependency management. But then I have two repositories.
- Is it required for me to expose all my .scss files, or maybe even put the whole Foundation project into laravel's public dir to make all work?

How do people usually approach using these frameworks together? They shouldn't interfere, but they still have totally different tooling.

Where do I put my foundation files? Keep it as composer module or inside `public`? How to refer to them? How to have one `build everything` command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the same issue as using Bootstrap SCSS version for Admin & Foundation SCSS for the frontend. I noticed also that both css frameworks come as composer packages however the issue you have with this approach is that you generally use other Javascript files in a development that will be merged also so using the composer versions just adds to the confusion.

The best solution i found was using either gulp or grunt with bower at the top level of your Laravel build. Rather that go through the configuration for you there is a good article at http://blog.elenakolevska.com/using-grunt-with-laravel-and-bootstrap/ that goes over a bootstrap integration but this can be tweaked for Foundation. This solution is good as grunt has many of the other popular javascript libraries that you may use in your project also..

Alternatively you could use an application like codekit and create a compass project to manage the merging & compiling of your assets into the public folder. As a side note if using git again your would need to exclude additional folders from your project.

If you think of your SCSS framework files as development assets there is no real need for them to be in the project as you only really need one version of Foundation on your development machine.

Your custom SCSS changes can be added to your Laravel project as modules ie a navigation module, via a private composer repo for the project or just added to the Compass project at development time. Your public folder should only be referencing the final merged style.css & java.js files for example. Any images from the framework can then just be copied over to the public folder ie icons etc..  Hope that helps..

Comment: Great answer but I want to throw my hat in the ring with Gulp rather than Grunt. Both are great but Gulp feels simpler to learn and use effectively.

Answer (score 7):

Personally I have a "static" directory which houses static files. That is where I use SASS watchers, grunt tasks and basically the entire front-end workflow. The results of that front-end build process gets added to a "production" Laravel `public` directory after getting built, etc.

A **pro** of this is that everything (static assets and laravel application) is separate.

A **con** is that updating Laravel views with any updates in HTML templates you may build in the `static` directory. If you update the templates, you may also need to update the view files, which becomes more tedious as you add more templating logic around the HTML in the views.

Just one suggestion.

Comment: Why do views become harder with this approach?

Comment: Disparity between HTML in your static folders and updating them within the view files. I was specifically thinking of HTML templates instead of CSS/JS or other asset management. I'll add that note in, thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you do, is to keep the "sources" of your front-end (so probably entire Foundation) in `static` directory, but their (compass, grunt tasks, etc.) output is the `public` dir, and this one is most likely entirely build-time populated, is that right?

Comment: Yep! That's it. Of course it depends on the project. Sometimes I don't bother using a full-on work-flow and just copy/paste files to the "production" spot as needed. In either case, HTML gets added to Laravel views. Changes in the HTML need to be reflected in the Views file as well, which can be tedious.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that concern, it might be because of my lack of experience (yet :)) with Laravel. Why is that a problem? Isn't just using Blade or other templating engine making it easy enough to keep the resulting HTML under control?

Comment: Imagine Developer A makes a static HTML page, then Developer B copies it into a template file and adds in template logic. Then imagine Developer A makes layout changes. Developer B then needs to incorporate all of those changes. The risk of missing small changes like a classname change is high. Diffs of the two files don't help because the template logic often splits up a HTML template into multiple files and adds in logic to loop around arrays, etc. It's not a "problem", it's just tedious. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Oh, now I get it! Sorry, I have never worked with people not modifying directly the template files, hence my confusion :) (also didn't see your answer for a couple of days, sorry again).

This is going to be a one-man project from start to end. I am just looking for the best practice, most perfect and clean approach. 

Also it came to me that I still have NO IDEA how all this should be tied together. Do I want to build my frontend files with Grunt, or should I create some magic artisan tasks that invoke… something? How do you usually involve external build tools in Laravel projects?

Comment: How do you use the SASS? I tried panique/laravel-sass but did not work.