# Adding Foundation 5 to Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, zurb-foundation, composer-php

I have been looking into Foundation 5 and would like to implement it in a project  I have been building with Laravel 4. Would I be able to use Composer to add Foundation to Laravel or would the two not function properly? Or would there be another way to combine the two? I'm still new to Laravel and am very new to Foundation so any insight on this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah, you can use Foundation 5 and Laravel 4 together. Since Foundation is a front-end framework and Laravel is a back-end framework, I don't see any reasons for them not to function together. You don't need Composer to install Foundation for Laravel, but there seems to be some packages on http://packagist.org/ that you can pull via Composer.

There's a short tutorial here:http://roxinlabs.com/2014/01/integrate-laravel-and-foundation-css-framework/ explaining how to use Foundation 5 with Laravel 4.

You might also want to look into here, for some best practices and more info: [Best practice for Laravel 4 + Zurb Foundation 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481564/best-practice-for-laravel-4-zurb-foundation-5)

Comment: Noooo the roxinlabs link isn't working! But I will check out the packagist one.

Comment: The link's working. To follow along with the tutorial, you'll have to download Foundation from http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download.html , extract the files to directories as specified in the tutorial and then follow along it.

Comment: I don't know why but the link isn't working for me. Must be a problem with my connection or something. I will get it to work somehow! I appreciate it!

Comment: I've added a link to another SO thread in my answer which might be of some more help.